# clipToBounds doesn't work when swiping cells

Tags: uitableview, swift, swipe

I have a custom cell with several labels hidden by default (the user sees all content when clicking on the cell). I'm changing the height of the cell and cell.clipToBounds = true to hide the labels. But this doesn't work for editable cells. When I start swiping the cell to left, the hidden content appears. I noticed that it works if I first expand the cell, collapse and the swipe, but stops working if I swipe another cell.
 Any suggestions how to hide it when the cell is swiped?

[image: clipToBounds not working for editable cells]

Comment: If you want the labels to be hidden, why not just set `label.hidden = true`? You can put them in an array or outlet collection to make it easier.

Comment: Aaron, sorry, I'm not quite sure how to do that. Just tried to create an array,  add all those labels to the array and using for loop to set them all to hidden, but I get a bunch of errors.

Comment: …what errors do you get? Please edit your question to show the code you're trying.

Comment: Aaron, I've set all the labels into an if else statement and it works. I was just confused on how to add the labels into one array and hide them all. If I do that, then I get an error "Array doesn't have hidden method". If you can give me an example how it's done, just for my knowledge, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the labels to an array.

Set `hidden` to `true`:

```
let labels = [firstLabel, secondLabel, etc.…]
for label in labels {
    label.hidden = true
}
```

Comment: I have many different objects to hide, such as UIImageViews and UISwitches, so I opted for a method instead of putting them in an array. This method is inside the cell controller:

`func hideAll(hide: Bool) {
        mySwitch.hidden = hide
        myLabel.hidden = hide`

I call this method in my TVC inside `heightForRow`. Still, doesn't work. Actually, once the views are hidden they do not appear again. But they DO appear when the swipe happens. I'm thinking this might be a xcode bug with the swipe for editing?

Comment: I was wrong above. Lack of understanding of tableViewCell's lifecycle led to the error. Will post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think that is a bug with the `setEditing` overriding or ignoring `clipsToBounds` during the animation and edit.

**The solution:**

You should hide all the elements which should not appear when the table is "closed", and unhide them when the table is expanded.

1) Create a `UITableViewCell` method to hide/unhide all elements you need:

```
func hideAll(hide: Bool) {
        myLabel.hidden = hide
        myUISwitch.hidden = hide
}
```

2) Call the above method when you initialize your cells. Usually will be called somewhere inside the cell, on an initializer, or will be called on `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. I check for the `cell.bounds.height` to determine if the cell is expanded or not:

```
//cell init code

//I'm calling this method from inside the cell, so I use self here.
//If you're calling this method from your controller you should
//target the cell with cell.bounds.height, as well as targeting the
//cell to call the method: cell.hideAll(Bool)
var hidden = (self.bounds.height < 80) //change this number depending on your collapsed and expanded cell heights
hideAll(hidden)
```

3) At this point (if the above method was called inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` or on a cell initializer) your method will be called when the cells are created and every time the cell **expands**. But not when the cell contracts (more on this ahead). So add some code in your `editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
        editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
        -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle{
            if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? CustomTableViewCell {
                cell.hideAll(cell.bounds.height < 80) //calls hideAll with a Bool argument, depending on height of cell
            }
            return .Delete
    }
```

`editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath` is called only on the cell you swipe, and doesn't call any of the delegate methods such as `heightForRowAtIndexPath`, so I believe this is the best place to hide your view items.

**Ok, that was the solution. Now the WHY:**

The true problem when you want to hide these cells is **when** to hide them. First you have to understand the cycle that swift goes through with `tableViewCell`s.

I'm assuming you're expanding/contracting the cells on the `heightForRowAtIndexPath`. Which semantically makes total sense. But let's suppose you have 3 cells (all expandable). I'm doing a `println()` whenever `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and `heightForRowAtIndexPath` are called. In the following example, I tapped on the first row, then on the second, then on the third. Observe the results on the console:

```
>>>> called didSelectRow at index 0
???? called heightForRow at index 0
???? called heightForRow at index 1
???? called heightForRow at index 2
???? called heightForRow at index 0
==== called cellForRow at index 0
???? called heightForRow at index 0

>>>> called didSelectRow at index 1
???? called heightForRow at index 0
???? called heightForRow at index 1
???? called heightForRow at index 2
???? called heightForRow at index 1
==== called cellForRow at index 1
???? called heightForRow at index 1

>>>> called didSelectRow at index 2
???? called heightForRow at index 0
???? called heightForRow at index 1
???? called heightForRow at index 2
???? called heightForRow at index 2
==== called cellForRow at index 2
???? called heightForRow at index 2
```

As you can see, when you `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, `heightForRowAtIndexPath` is called multiple times, cyclically, until swift is sure it has all the heights right. Meanwhile, `cellForRow` is called **only** on the cell you selected.

So if your cells auto-collapse when you select another cell, you have to realize they're not running any code (such as the method to hide elements) when they collapse, because `cellForRowAtIndexPath` was called only on the tapped cell.

You **could** hide/unhide inside your `heightForRow` code, but that code is called so many times that it's really not optimal. Code should be called only once when you need it. So the best solution IMO is to call it inside the `editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath`

Answer (score 1):

In your `UITableViewCell` subclass, override the `willTransitionToState(state: UITableViewCellStateMask)` method and set `contentView.clipToBounds` to true like this:

```
override func willTransitionToState(state: UITableViewCellStateMask) {
    super.willTransitionToState(state)

    contentView.clipsToBounds = true
}
```

From now on, it will clip the cell's subviews correctly.

Answer (score 0):

try setting the contentView clipsToBounds property to true.
normally you shouldn't mess with the cell as a view.

**Swift**

```
cell.contentView.clipsToBounds = true
```

**Obj-C**

```
cell.contentView.clipsToBounds = YES
```